# Alinhar verticalmente texto entre dois botões no Ionic 2

Tags: ionic2

Estou com dificuldades em alinhar verticalmente o valor entre 2 botões. 
Segue o trecho do código e o resultado:

```
<ion-list>
```

```
<ion-thumbnail item-start>
  <img src={{produto.foto}}>
</ion-thumbnail>
<h2>{{ produto.nomeProduto }}</h2>
<h3>{{ produto.nomeMedida }}</h3>
<p class="pValor"> {{ produto.valorProduto | currency:'BRL':true:'1.2-2' }} </p>

<div item-end >  
  <button ion-button round>
    <ion-icon name="remove"></ion-icon>
  </button>

    {{ produto.quantidadeProduto }}

  <button ion-button  round>
    <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
  </button>
</div>
```

[image: resultado do código]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente colocar seu texto dentro de uma div com o seguinte comando do Ionic

```
<div margin-top>
  {{ produto.quantidadeProduto }}
</div>
```

Se não der certo ou ficar com dúvida em algo, use a documentação do Ionic, ela é bem completinha!

Ionic: [Documentação CSS Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-utilities/)

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado! consegui resolver com o código abaixo.

```
<span  style="vertical-align: -26%;" item-left>{{ produto.quantidadeProduto }}</span>
```